# How to simplify graphql response

Tags: graphql

For example my graphql's query is:

```
products {
  name,
  price,
  brand {
    name
  }
}
```

Which produces this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Black Dress",
        "price": 520,
        "brand": {
          "name": "Coach"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can this

```
"brand": {
  "name": "Coach"
}
```

be simplified to this somehow?

```
"brandName": "Coach"
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, without any additional dependencies and if you don't want to update schema, you cannot control the shape of the object returned by GraphQL if you like to control the shape that can be possible by graphql-leveler.

The graphql-leveler will provide a method call _get through which you can manage the shape of your object you can do simply:

```
{
    brandName: _get(products: 'brand.name')
}
```

Note: to use graphql-leveler, simply add graphql-leveler to your dependencies, require LevelerObjectType, and use it instead of GraphQLObjectType. Done!

Comment: does this `graphql-leveler ` have to be enabled on server side?    from a graphql playground, it returns an error `cannot query field "_get" on ...`